# 'variable or field sort declared void': in template function declaration

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T>
void sort(T::iterator begin, T::iterator end){ ... }
```

I get this error on the function declaration:

```
'variable or field 'sort' declared void'
```

I tried adding `std::` before the `T`s in the parameters, didn't help. Tried adding `typename` before the `T`s, no luck. What's the problem?

Comment: two issues, 1. missing `typename`, 2. `T` is non-deducible, or maybe you meant [this syntax](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef6a387957a28e77) ?

Comment: Normally, you just use `T` as the iterator type. `void sort(T begin, T end)`